# How to check where do my updates come from?

Tags: updates

Just switched the motherboard of my Galaxy Note 4, now I am wondering where do the phone gets its updates from? How to check this in Android? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way how to extract the Over The Air (OTA) update url.

However the integrated update client usually prints the used URLs on logcat if you trigger a search for update manually in the settings app.

Therefore you need to do:

1. Enable Developer mode (if not already done)
2. Enable the Android Debug bridge (ADB) in the development settings menu
3. Connect your phone via USB to your PC (the PC need a working ADB drivers and runtime)
4. Execute `adb logcat`
5. Open the "search for update" on your phone and trigger it (usually it is in the settings app section system)
6. Check the logcat for urls (you can filter logcat for HTTPS URL e.g. on Windows you can use `adb logcat | find "https://"`)

Depending on the number of active apps you will see a number of messages with URLs in it. Then you will be able to identify the server your phone connects with for the update check. I assume if an update is available the download of the update will also be visible in logcat.

Note that those server are usually not designed to be browsed by a web server, they are only providing update to the devices.

Comment: Thank you! Cannot believe it is so complicated. It is such a critical security/privacy issue.

Comment: @Martin: Why is it a security issue that end users can not view the update URLs? On Android you can't change anything on the update system therefore as an end user it is only of interest that it works and that your manufacturer provides updates. The updates are signed anyway therefore how they are transferred is of no interest.

Comment: Right, but for instance I just bought a mother board from AliExpress. And I have no idea where my updates come from. Sounds a little scary to me. But thanks a lot anyway!